# Setting colors in a bar chart using Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to have different colors on a bar chart, based on the values.

I have something like this :

```
    for(var i=0; i<table.length;i++){
        colors[i]=new Object();
        if (table[i][1]<=300){
            colors[i].color='blue';
        }
        else if (table[i][1]<=800){
            colors[i].color='yellow';
        }
        else{
            colors[i].color='red';
        }
    }
```

So "colors" is an array of objects, and every object has a color field. Then I do this :

```
    var options = { series: colors};
```

But this doesn't work. So I made easier tests like these:

```
   colors: ['black','blue','white','blue','blue','blue','blue']
```

Doesnt work: just the FIRST color is taken for the whole chart.

```
   series: [{color:'black'},{color:'blue'}]
```

Same effect.

Can anyone please help me do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this code : http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QHJA6/